# Sharepoint WebPart not installing

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

What tips do you have for debugging a WebPart that is not installing? One tip per response.

Comment: This is a wide open question. Can you be more specific by "not installing"?

Comment: The wide open question was so that we hade a list of points to work through.

My problem is that it installs but when I click on the XML icon or try adding the part to the page I get an error

Comment: @John: That looks like a pretty specific error. You might have better luck posting this as its own question with detail about how the web part has been constructed.

Comment: @Alex Removed error from comments will ask antoher question for that but this question still stands...

Comment: If you want this to be some sort of a checklist for debugging webparts, you should make this a community wiki

Comment: @ashwnacharya now a wiki

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common problems for newbies is probably code access security. A great article for troubleshooting this is [Common Security Pitfalls for Web Part Developers](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2005/06/23/WebPartSecurity.aspx) by Jan Tielens. It was written for SharePoint 2003 / WSS 2.0 but the same principles apply in SharePoint 2007 / WSS 3.0.

The error is usually something like "A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Web Part Page cannot be displayed or imported because it is not registered on this site as safe."

Answer (score 0):

One Quick Solution I can think of seeing your Error message is that,you somewhere in the code have a <%%>. You can try wrapping that part with

```
<div id="temp" runat="server"> var x= '<% = x.ClientID %>' </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint does not allow Inline scripting for any content except that in the _layouts folder out of the box. You need to move your inline code block to the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in the constructor and debug it.  You probably don't want to do anything in the constructor.  I think we may have been doing a RunWithElevatedPrivileges there and that was a problem when adding a web part to a page, but not using the web part if it was already on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I am using webparts in sharepoint and I didn't find a way for debugging. I just copy the code into another application to debug it